# Can't delete a taxonomy field

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to remove a field from a powershell script.

The field is a taxonomy field.

However, it does not works, with this error:

> Site columns which are included in content types cannot be deleted. Remove all references to this site column prior to deleting it.

But the field is not used anywhere:

- all webs recycle bin are empty
- the site recycle bin is empty
- no content type references the field
- no list references the field.

I try to remove first the associated note field, but the behavior is the same for the note field.

Here is what I tried:

```
$web = get-spweb http://mysitecollection
$site = $web.Site

$site.RecycleBin.Count 
# ==> outputs 0
0..($site.AllWebs.Count-1) | % {
    $subWeb = $site.allwebs[$_]
    Write-host -nonewline:($_%20) $subWeb.RecycleBin.Count
    $subWeb.dispose()
}
# ==> outputs a bunch of 0


$fld = $web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("MyTaxField")
$fldNote = $web.Fields[$fld.TextField]



$fld.ListsFieldUsedIn().Count
# ==> outputs 0
($web.ContentTypes | ? { $_.FieldLinks[$fld.Id] }).Count
# ==> outputs 0

$fldNote.ListsFieldUsedIn().Count
# ==> outputs 0

($web.ContentTypes | ? { $_.FieldLinks[$fldnote.Id] }).Count
# ==> outputs 0



$fldNote.Delete()
# exception
$fld.Delete()
# exception
```

Any suggestion?